# How to get source code from compiled file of vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

I lost my vuejs source code due to of laptop crash. I have files which are compiled by vuejs. Is it possible to get source code from compiled file (files genereated by `npm run build` in vuecli 2).

I googled it but nothing found. Is there any tool to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I found two links for you,

First solution is to use babel (quite difficult) : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/any-method-or-workaround-to-decompile-dynamically-compiled-components/16334/3

Second solution (the best approach), if your compiled files are not in production mode you can check them with vue devtool : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/any-method-or-workaround-to-decompile-dynamically-compiled-components/16334/3

Hope this will help !

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `npm run build` will build the file in production mode. 
 
Vue Devtools will not detect Vue, but inspecting them is not possible since it is already compiled in production mode.

**Yes**. It's possible to extract "source code", but it will be compiled. 
 **No**. It's not possible to get the whole project in its structure back from the compiled file.

*tl;dr*:  **No**, in your case.