# Vue.js: How to open/handle existing project by SourceMap or bundled files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, source-maps

Sorry for my stupid question.  I am new in vue.js.
I have vue.js project without source codes. I have to read Vue components and improve it. But some friends told me that it is imposimble to convert it back. Is it really imposible?

Project file structure:

```
/js
-app.js
-app.js.map
-manifest.js
-manifest.js.map
-vendor.js
-vendor.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On vue `>=2` that's basically impossible.

Take a look here:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/any-method-or-workaround-to-decompile-dynamically-compiled-components/16334

[How to get source code from compiled file of vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137601/how-to-get-source-code-from-compiled-file-of-vuejs)