# How can I decompile, compiled vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component rendered like

```
function render() {
  var _vm = this;
  var _h = _vm.$createElement;
  var _c = _vm._self._c || _h;
  return _c('div', [_c('input'), _vm._v(_vm._s(_vm.val)), _c('input')])
}
```

And I want to convert again to

```
<template><div><input>{{val}}<input/></div></template>
```

Is it possible? If is it, How can I do?
I'm searching something like reverse version of this => https://template-explorer.vuejs.org/
But I'm failed after two days.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. For what reason do you need to decompile it?

Comment: I lost my project files and I'm trying to get it back with sourcemap files.
It seems I have to rewrite it based with those compiled files huh?

Comment: Oof that doesn't sound fun. Do you not push your files to Github or back them up somehow?

Comment: I was storing in my external hdd and they are all gone. May I can write a function works with callback and convert to a sketchy template,

Comment: That sucks. Judging by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62847548/12701949) it's *almost* impossible. Which basically means, it'd be easier for you to just build the files from what you can remember